# Find scalars such that equation holds?

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry

Given the equation:

$(2,-14,8)x+(-3,21,-12)y=\vec 0$

Find the scalars x and y, not both zero, such that the above equation holds.

My attempt:

I tried solving the equation system $2x-3y=0, -14x+21y=0, 8x-12y=0$ but I only obtained trivial solutions, i.e. $x=0, y=0$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Note that the three equations are the same equation. Do you know another solution to $2x=3y$?

Comment: $(-3,2)$ appears to be a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your effort makes a lot of sense! But you **not only** find the trivial solution: your system of equations is correct and it is equivalent to the only equation:
$$
2x−3y=0,
$$
whose solution is
$$
y=\frac{2}{3}x.
$$
So, all the ordered couples of the kind $(x,y)=(x,\frac{2}{3}x)$ are solutions.

The *trivial* solution $(0,0)$ is an example, other ones are $(1,\frac{2}{3})$ and $(3,2)$ or $(-3,-2)$ but one linear equation in two variables has an infinity of such ordered couples of values as solutions.